# Kubernetes Kustomize: replace variable in patch file

Tags: kubernetes, kustomize

Given the following kustomize patch:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flux
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: some-name
          args:
            - --some-key=some-value
            ...
            - --git-url=https://user:${PASSWORD}@domain.de
```

I want to use `kubectl apply -k` and somehow pass a value for `${PASSWORD}` which I can set from my build script.

The only solution I got to work so far was replacing the `${PASSWORD}` with `sed`, but I would prefer a kustomize solution.

Comment: you should try to find a way to pass the password to the container using a `Secret` instead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Jonas already suggested you should consider using `Secret`. It's nicely described in [this](https://blog.stack-labs.com/code/kustomize-101/) article.

> I want to use kubectl apply -k and somehow pass a value for
>   ${PASSWORD} which I can set from my build script.

I guess your script can store the generated password as a variable or save it to some file. You can easily create a `Secret` as follows:

```
$ kustomize edit add secret sl-demo-app --from-literal=db-password=$PASSWORD
```

or from a file:

```
$ kustomize edit add secret sl-demo-app --from-file=file/path
```

As you can read in the mentioned article:

> These commands will modify your `kustomization.yaml` and add a
>   `SecretGenerator` inside it.
>
> ```
> apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
> kind: Kustomization
>
> bases:
> - ../../base
>
> patchesStrategicMerge:
> - custom-env.yaml
> - replica-and-rollout-strategy.yaml
>
> secretGenerator:
> - literals:
>   - db-password=12345
>   name: sl-demo-app
>   type: Opaque
> ```

`kustomize build` run in your project directory will create among others following `Secret`:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  db-password: MTIzNDU=
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: sl-demo-app-6ft88t2625
type: Opaque
...
```

More details you can fine in the [article](https://blog.stack-labs.com/code/kustomize-101/).

> If we want to use this secret from our deployment, we just have, like
>   before, to add a new layer definition which uses the secret.
>
> For example, this file will mount the db-password value as
>   environement variables
>
> ```
> apiVersion: apps/v1
> kind: Deployment
> metadata:
>   name: sl-demo-app
> spec:
>   template:
>     spec:
>       containers:
>       - name: app
>         env:
>         - name: "DB_PASSWORD"
>           valueFrom:
>             secretKeyRef:
>               name: sl-demo-app
>               key: db.password
> ```

In your `Deployment` definition file it may look similar to this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flux
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: some-name
          env:
            - name: "PASSWORD"
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: git-secret
                  key: git.password
          args:
            - --some-key=some-value
            ...
            - --git-url=https://user:${PASSWORD}@domain.de
```